# How to get pip to automatically install local wheel dependencies

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-poetry, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I've built a gizmo wheel which has a dependency on an internally developed (transfunctioner) wheel which is not available on a public PyPy server. The external dependencies are automatically downloaded and installed, however I am unable to find a way to get the local wheel to be installed, despite my best attempts as shown in the my pyproject.toml extract below:

```ini
[project]
name = "Gizmo"
version = "1.5.0"
requires-python = ">=3.9"
dependencies = [
    "pycairo~=1.21.0",
    "PyGObject~=3.42.0",
    "PyGObject-stubs~=1.0.0",
    "acme_transfunctioner>=1.3.0"
]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pycairo="^1.21.0"
PyGObject="^3.42.0"
PyGObject-stubs="^1.0.0"
acme_transfunctioner = { version = ">=1.3.0", file = "dist/depend/acme_transfunctioner-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl" }
```

Error message:

```
$ pip install dist/gizmo-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl 
Processing ./dist/gizmo-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycairo~=1.21.0 (from gizmo==1.5.0)
  Using cached pycairo-1.21.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyGObject~=3.42.0 (from gizmo==1.5.0)
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.2-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyGObject-stubs~=1.0.0 (from gizmo==1.5.0)
  Using cached PyGObject_stubs-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (159 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gizmo to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement acme_transfunctioner>=1.3.0 (from gizmo) (from versions: none)
```

Comment: I do not think path dependencies work for this. They are something that is specific to Poetry only. As far as I know they only work if you run `poetry install`. I am not sure that the path is written in the wheel at all. It is likely that the dependency is written in the wheel without the path part.